# Workflow in OneDrive for business

Tags: office-365, onedrive-for-business

Please let me know how can create a workflow in onedrive for business?

Is there a tool like SharePoint designer to create a workflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create Workflow for Onedrive but if you want workflow like functionality then you can try Microsoft Flow. There are various triggers/events  which you can define for initiating your Flow (seen in screenshot below)

you can start creating flow by logging in to https://flow.microsoft.com/

to learn basics you can visit https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/getting-started/

[image: flow for onedrive]